# Search breaks collapsible DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

So I have a current HTML page I'm building which is to contain a list of "experts" along with their category of expertise and their location.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dgaz8n5k/) is the relevant JSFiddle.

As you can see below this is my HTML followed by the jQuery I am using for my search feature.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

      $('.ui-content div').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('data-search-term', $(this).text().toLowerCase());
      });

      $('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function() {

        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        $('.ui-content div').each(function() {

          if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
            $(this).show();
          } else {
            $(this).hide();
          }

        });

      });
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="live-search-box" placeholder="Search Here" />
  </div>

  <div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
        <h3>Category</h3>
        <p>Defenition</p>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
          <h3>Sub-category</h3>
          <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <h3>Location</h3>
            <p>Point of Contact</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /section 1A -->
        </div>
        <!-- /section 1 -->
      </div>

      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
        <h3>Category2</h3>
        <p>Defenition2</p>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
          <h3>Sub-Category</h3>
          <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <h3>Location</h3>
            <p>Point of Contact2</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I got the Search to work correctly, with the only problem being that when I use or clear the search, it breaks the collapsible

sections that I have in my HTML.

Any help on how I can get the  to be collapsible during and after the search would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: i think the best thing for you to do would be to add an event listener for a delete key (keycode 8) and that way you would be able to tell if someone had deleted characters form the initial length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `display: none` in your CSS by the use of `.hide()`. But then you never reset it after the search field is cleared. You should add an additional check for re-displaying the hidden elements.

```
if (!searchTerm || searchTerm=='') {
    $(this).show();
}
```

If you place that within your `.each()` loop, you should be good on that front.

But the other issue is resolving the console error you have when the search field is empty. I modified your `if` check to check to see if `searchTerm` exists yet.

```
if (searchTerm && $(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dgaz8n5k/5/

---

**Update**

I had misread your question to understand what you were really asking. There are a few things that need to be worked on (from my point of view). But to solve your problem, use the following code

```
  $('.ui-content > div').each(function () {
    if (searchTerm && $(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
```

The problem is with your selector `$('.ui-content div')`. You are looping through every child `div` of `.ui-content`. Then when `.show()` is called, you are setting each of those to `display:block`, forcing them to no longer be collapsed. I'm not quite sure why it breaks the toggle yet. But I'm sure it's because the child styling has been overrode.

So the solution is to select just the immediate descendants of `.ui-content` with a [child selector: `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

I still am using the check on `searchTerm` within the `if` block.

---

**Update 2**

The updated fiddle that reflects my previous update: https://jsfiddle.net/dgaz8n5k/17/

Comment: This does have the unfortunate side-effect of removing the `display:none` for all children as well. So initially all of your boxes are collapsed. I assume you want the same functionality. So you may want to reference the specific parent elements themselves to reset them.

Comment: This is not answering the OP's question (ironic given your comment on my answer). When you clear the search in your fiddle, the collapsibles are all fully opened, and have stopped working.

Comment: @Toby touche! I understand what OP meant by broken now. I guess OP has several problems that needed to be solved. Your solution does fix that problem, but not the others. And it looks fine for his current example, but being that `visiblity:hidden` doesn't remove elements from the DOM, when his list grows beyond 2, it would look odd to me to set visibility to hidden.

Comment: it was like a circular reference! You were looking at a different problem. I think you are right about the growing list. But the problem with using show() and hide() seems to be that they conflict with the collapsible functionality he is using.... needs a rethink.

Comment: @Toby Ok, how about the use of a child selector in OP's original selector. It preserves all of the search function & allows for the collapsible feature to function. It also removes elements from the DOM appropriately now, and also stops the console error.

Comment: I didn't notice that he was applying the hide() to all children. Your solution is the correct one. Might be worth editing for OP to accept. Upvoting.

Comment: @EnigmaRM Thank you for the solution! Though this still does not fix the issue unfortunately. Show() and Hide() is actually working as intended, as it was my choice to hide all children that do not match the keyword in search, The problem that I really nee help in fixing is that the <div> collapsible are not collapsing/un-collapsing when clicked during the search and after the search is cleared. Please look back into your jfiddle and clear the search, the DIV is broken as it's all uncollapse and it won't function properly when clicked. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Halon Nice of you to participate in your question! :).  I'm guessing you didn't take the time to ready my update. I had not posted a new fiddle, but just added the updated code necessary to change your original fiddle. I've now updated my answer with my original update into the fiddle. The expand/collapse works for me doing a search or after clearing a search.

Comment: @EnigmaRM Thank you! I did have the chance to read the update, but I guess I might have confused myself with the 2 separate updates. It works great now, thank you for your time! :)

Comment: @EnigmaRM One more question, is it possible for the search to actually drill down and hide the DIV that doesn't have the search keyword in it? Or is that what broke it? Thanks!

Comment: @J.Halon, sure it's possible. But you'd need additional logic. I'd recommend posing that as a separate SO question. What broke the original collapse/expand feature was that `show()` and `hide()` were being  used on too many child elements and not properly removing them when you expected. So the solution was to limit the number of children that were affected by show/hide

Comment: @EnigmaRM I really appreciate the time and knowledge you put into this! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the css directly, instead of calling show() and hide() it seems to work how you want. I would guess that show() does something recursive..

```
if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) {
   $(this).css({visibility:"visible"});
} else {
   $(this).css({visibility:"hidden"});
}
```

Comment: this does not solve OPs problem. He has DOM elements that are set to `display: none` by the use of `.hide()` Changing the code to set `visibility:hidden` results in the same issue when the search field is cleared: that his items do not reappear on the screen.

Comment: The OP's stated problem is not that his items do not reappear. It is that when they reappear, they are all broken - ie. fully open, and no longer collapsible. Seems fairly clear question - "when I use or clear the search, it breaks the collapsible sections that I have in my HTML." My suggested change works fine... https://jsfiddle.net/srqogea0/